# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException - delete table view row

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm developing a table view based application using Swift. Ive been trying all day to delete a tableview row but I keep getting this exception. Not sure what this is. here the code I have to delete the row. Not sure what else to try to be honest. It should be a simple task and Swift should be making it easy for us but this really is holding me up.

code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            // do something with unwrappedIndexPath.row

            context.deleteObject(myData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSManagedObject)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            abort()
        }

    }
}
```

Erro:

```
(
    "<MyData: 0x10bba1a90> (entity: MyData; id: 0xd0000000001c0000 <x-coredata://8A0231EE-899F-48F9-953B-CAB1252FD1D0/MyData/p7> ; data: <fault>)"
)
<MyData: 0x10d84ba20> (entity: MyData; id: 0xd000000000300000 <x-coredata://8A0231EE-899F-48F9-953B-CAB1252FD1D0/MyData/p12> ; data: {
    name = test;
    skills = te;
})
Data Saved
(
    "<MyData: 0x10bba1a90> (entity: MyData; id: 0xd0000000001c0000 <x-coredata://8A0231EE-899F-48F9-953B-CAB1252FD1D0/MyData/p7> ; data: {\n    name = Rob;\n    skills = Dev;\n})",
    "<MyData: 0x10bf1dec0> (entity: MyData; id: 0xd000000000300000 <x-coredata://8A0231EE-899F-48F9-953B-CAB1252FD1D0/MyData/p12> ; data: <fault>)"
)
2014-06-13 21:51:51.452 coreDataApp[2090:38878] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3185.20/UITableView.m:1487
2014-06-13 21:51:51.487 coreDataApp[2090:38878] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100848e35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001022f49a0 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100848c9a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000100cdb6fb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000101190b3b -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 11785
    5   coreDataApp                         0x000000010000454c _TFC11coreDataApp23dataTableViewController9tableViewfS0_FTGSQCSo11UITableView_18commitEditingStyleOSC27UITableViewCellEditingStyle17forRowAtIndexPathGSQCSo11NSIndexPath__T_ + 2332
    6   coreDataApp                         0x0000000100004927 _TToFC11coreDataApp23dataTableViewController9tableViewfS0_FTGSQCSo11UITableView_18commitEditingStyleOSC27UITableViewCellEditingStyle17forRowAtIndexPathGSQCSo11NSIndexPath__T_ + 103
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001011b1e51 -[UITableView animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 114
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001013409db -[UITableViewCell _swipeDeleteButtonPushed] + 60
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001010c4333 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001011c086d -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001011bfc3f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010144efb7 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7670
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000101105d66 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1041
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000101106993 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001010d7dd1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001010e2dda _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 11315
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001010bfc5f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1461
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010077fbd1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010077522d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010077485d __CFRunLoopRun + 861
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100774296 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104462ce4 GSEventRunModal + 161
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001010c3308 UIApplicationMain + 2994
    24  coreDataApp                         0x00000001000096ad top_level_code + 77
    25  coreDataApp                         0x00000001000096ea main + 42
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102852145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: The tableView argument comes from an optional which is used without checking. How did you ensure it has a value?

Comment: read... Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the delete the object from your data model

```
myData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
```

This is not really a Swift problem, the same would happen in Obj-C.

Comment: I'm using an NSArray and not an NSMutableArray

Comment: @LedK Then you should reconsider making it a mutable one. You have to remove the object from your data model. That's what your table is reading, right?

Answer (score 1):

Safer way by testing both optionals (tableView and indexPath) before unwrapping:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        // do something with unwrappedIndexPath.row

        if let ind = indexPath? {
            context.deleteObject(myData.objectAtIndex(ind.row) as NSManagedObject)
            tableView?.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([ind], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            abort()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same exception gets shown. could it be that the myData is an NSArray and not a NSMutableArray?

Comment: @LedK: Whoops, I didn't see the other '!' in the indexPath argument. Same issue there. I will modify my answer.

Comment: @LedK: Regarding myData: You didn't post the code for that. I guess it's a property. You have to tell us what type it is.

Comment: This code won't work without if let ind = indexPath and if let tv = tableView

Comment: Can I send you my code somehow so you can have a look not sure how to explain it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55607/discussion-between-jewirth-and-led-k).

Answer (score 1):

In tableView data manipulation the order matters a lot.
delete the object from your data model first, then delete the row.

```
myData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
tableView?.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([ind], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

The thread is a bit old, but for the sake of helping others coming from a search, in swift 4, this looks like this :

```
myData.remove(indexPath.row)
tableView?.deleteRows(at: [indexPaths], with: .Automatic)
```